# HowTo: Overwrite Object property with property from another Object

Tags: javascript

So, and as is shown in the attached image, I have two objects, `addedBack` and `Comments`. What I want to do is overwrite the array of comments in `addedBack`, with the array comments in `Comments`.

I attempted:

```html
const tempVal = Object.assign(addedBack, Comments)
```

But the value of `tempVal` just contained `addedBack`, without merging `Comments` into it.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: If it is as you said, then `Object.assign` is broken, which is highly unlikely. Can you provide [mcve] and an example of the input and the expected output? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach should work:

```js
var addedBack = { comments: ['that sucks', 'terrible', '0 stars', "It doesn't matter--we'll all still die in the end"]};
var Comments = { comments: ['fantastic', '5 stars', 'I love you', 'A stunning achievement']};

console.log(addedBack.comments);     // <= ["that sucks", "terrible", "0 stars", "It doesn't matter--we'll all still die in the end"]
Object.assign(addedBack, Comments);   // Could also just do "addedBack.comments = Comments.comments;" if you only care about this one property
console.log(addedBack.comments);     // <= ["fantastic", "5 stars", "I love you", "A stunning achievement"]

// Changing Comments.comments also changes addedBack.comments
Comments.comments[0] = 'If I had a tomato, you would be covered in ketchup right now.';
console.log(addedBack.comments);     // <= ["If I had a tomato, you would be covered in ketchup right now.", "5 stars", "I love you", "A stunning achievement"]
```

Note, however, that Object.assign makes a shallow copy of object properties. Comments.comments is a reference to an array, and that reference gets copied to addedBack.comments. After Object.assign, then both Comments.comments and addedBack.comments refer to the same array. As a result, if you change Comments.comments, you will also change addedBack.comments, as shown in the example above. If this behavior will be problematic for you, then your best option is probably:

```
addedBack.comments = Comments.comments.slice();
```

instead of `Object.assign`. slice() on an array will return a copy of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a simple data structure (array), you can just do something like this:

```
addedBack.comments = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Comments.comments));
```

<strike>This might not work in all cases but it will work here to make a shallow copy.</strike>

This is another good [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript%20Stackoverflow) about cloning.

Comment: This makes a deep copy of `comments`, not a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one for you.

If you use Object.assign, it will return an object with the properties of the first object overwritten by the second.

```
let obj1 = { x : [ '1', '2', '3' ] };
let obj2 = { x : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] };

let obj3 = Object.assign ( obj1, obj2 );
```

That third object will contain:

```
{ x : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] }
```

It makes sense: "assign the properties/values of obj2, to obj1". Exactly as if you did this manually, it'll just overwrite the existing prop/val.

This also has the benefit of leaving the originals intact, say, if you wanted to test the property is actually different from the original or some such.

I mean...TESTING! (Wow look I have more credibility now).

(Object.assign is not broken).

Answer (score 0):

This final solution was to `import update from 'immutability-helper'`.